# Polars read glob and add column for file path read

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

Is it possible to add the file path for each record into a new column when reading a glob of file paths into a polars df?

I have ~18k files which I am merging together to do some processing. The csvs don't have a unique identifier (e.g. `user_id`) for each record in the data set but the file path does:

```
C:\Projects\data\000\data\datetime1.csv
C:\Projects\data\000\data\datetime2.csv
C:\Projects\data\001\data\datetime1.csv
C:\Projects\data\001\data\datetime2.csv
C:\Projects\data\002\data\datetime1.csv
C:\Projects\data\003\data\datetime1.csv
...
...
```

where `000`, `001`, `002`, `003` in the file paths are the unique identifiers for that particular csv. If I work on processing each file individually then merge back together I can parse out the identifier from the path but I'd like to avoid processing each file individually by using glob and `pl.scan_csv()`:

```py
import polars as pl
from glob import glob
files = glob(r'C:\Projects\data\*\data\*.csv')
df = pl.scan_csv(files, skip_rows=6, new_columns=["latitude", "longitude", "zero", "altitude", "epoch", "date_str", "time_str"], dtypes={"latitude": pl.Float64, "longitude": pl.Float64, "zero": pl.Int8, "altitude": pl.Float64, "epoch": pl.Float64, "date_str": pl.String, "time_str": pl.String}, rechunk=True)
```

Comment: It has been previously "rejected" as a feature request: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9096 - I think it should be added because it would be even more useful when doing over-the-network globbing e.g. `pl.scan_csv("http://.../foo*csv")`